# How to install python pip without Internet connection?

Tags: python, pip

My python is 2.7.5,

```
-bash-4.2$ python --version
Python 2.7.5
```

By default it doesn't have python pip.

My Linux is Redhat ERHL 7.3.

```
-bash-4.2$ cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3 (Maipo)
```

I have also checked that I don't have python-pip in Linux repository.

```
-bash-4.2$ yum search python-pip
Loaded plugins: product-id, rhnplugin, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
*Note* Spacewalk repositories are not listed below. You must run this command as root to access Spacewalk repositories.
cloudera-manager                                                                                                                 7/7
Warning: No matches found for: python-pip
No matches found
```

My way to install pip is using `get-pip.py`.
I got the `get-pip.py` from https://packaging.python.org/installing/

The download link is https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

I downloaded it for my windows laptop and ftp upload it to the Linux server.

When I ran `python get-pip.py`. 
It tried a connection to the Internet.

```
-bash-4.2$ python get-pip.py
Collecting pip
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x35755d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable',)': /simple/pip/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x3575a90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable',)': /simple/pip/
```

Question:

- Where does it connect to?
- Can I setup a private repository?
- Is it pypi repo?
- Can I use static web server for this pypi repo?
- How can I set the get-pip.py to point the connection to my private repo?

Comment: From where did you obtain `get-pip.py`?  The version I found has a base85 blob representing a zip file at the end, though just downloading from [the source](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/) seems much more reasonable

Comment: @Fox, I added the download link into my question details.

Comment: pip is in the EPEL repository, if you can add that, use it.

Comment: Edit `get-pip.py`, changing `with open(pip_zip, "wb") as fp` to `with open ("pip.zip", "wb") as fp`.  Remove `bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)`.  Run it, unzip `pip.zip`, and copy the new `pip` directory to `/usr/lib/pythonX.Y` or wherever your system keeps Python libraries.  I'm not posting this as an answer because I consider it "hackish" and bad

Comment: If you have recent enough version of Python, you may be able to use [`ensurepip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html#module-ensurepip).

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to go the OS way, you can also download the source archive from PyPI and install it manually.

1. Go to https://pypi.org/project/pip/#files
2. Download and extract the archive file.
3. Run `python setup.py install`

Answer (score 3):

Download the .rpm from [EPEL repo](https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/) and install using yum command.

https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7Server/x86_64/Packages/p/python2-pip-8.1.2-8.el7.noarch.rpm

Answer (score 1):

If you have recent enough version of Python (3.4 or higher), you may be able to use [`ensurepip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html#module-ensurepip).

ensurepip does not contact PyPI, but instead rely on a private copy of pip stored inside the standard library ([src](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0453/#id32)).